# SQL query error query empty

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    include "head-main.php";
    include "conn.php";

    if(isset($_GET)){ $var = $_GET["cat"]; }
    $data = mysql_query('SELECT kampword FROM data_dict where category=$var');

   $retval = mysql_query( $data, $conn );

     if(! $retval ) {
   die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)) {
   echo "World :{$row['kampword']}  <br> ".
     "--------------------------------<br>";
  }

  ?>
```

i'm new in programming, i can't trace what's wrong with my code, can you help me. i'm trying to print some data on my DB

i always get this error
"Could not get data: Query was empty"

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: is `$var` a string? and does it have value?

Comment: Variables doesn't are interpreted in simple quotes.

Comment: test SELECT kampword FROM data_dict where category=$var directly to db from for example phpadmin, relpacing $var with a actual value... what do you get?

Comment: Why are you running the query against the SQL query, then another query against the results? Follow the advice and switch to PDO or mysqli, and only run the query once.

Comment: maybe $data = mysql_query("SELECT kampword FROM data_dict where category=".$var."");

Comment: when u fetching a single results there's no need to loop

Answer (score 0):

You are calling twice the `mysql_query` function for nothing. Try to replace your lines with :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["cat"])) { 
    $var = $_GET["cat"];
    $retval = mysql_query('SELECT kampword FROM data_dict where category=$var');
}else {
    $retval = false;
}
```

Comment: the error was gone, but it's still doesn't fetch data on my database

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT kampword FROM data_dict where category=$var");
```

or

```
$data = mysql_query('SELECT kampword FROM data_dict where category="'.$var.'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(isset($_GET["cat"])){ $var = $_GET["cat"]; }
```